# No module named 'gi' when running ibus-setup

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, ibus

I am trying to run `ibus-setup` and getting the following

```
$ ibus-setup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
```

Neigther of the following helped:

```
pip install gi
pip install pgi
sudo apt install python-gi
sudo apt install python3-gi
```

How to run `ibus-setup`?

Comment: Try running `sudo ibus-setup`. It might work!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message and it was caused by using non-system python interpreter. When asking:

```
which python3 -a
```

I got two paths: `~/anaconda3/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3`

Solution was to give priority to system python interpreter by:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because ibus-setup is runs `python /usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py` which on your system is python 3. You can fix this by running `python2 /usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py`.